# How to access off-cell mouse position inside an EventHandler?

Tags: front-end, dynamic

Consider the following example. First, I print the dynamically updated value of the actual position of the mouse, then I print `pt`, which is the same but is only updated when the `EventHandler` object (a grey rectangle) is clicked and dragged.

```
Dynamic@MousePosition@"ScreenScaled"
Dynamic@pt
Deploy@EventHandler[
  Graphics[{Gray, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 50, AspectRatio -> 2],
  {"MouseDragged" :> (pt = MousePosition@"ScreenScaled")}]
```

This has two issues:

1. While `Dynamic@MousePosition@"ScreenScaled"` updates correctly when the mouse moves anywhere on the screen, `pt` is constrained to be updated only in the cell where the `EventHandler` is when the rectangle is dragged. The `EventHandler` **DOES** register and display movement outside the gray `Rectangle` (and thus outside the `EventHandler`), though it **DOES NOT** register movement outside of the cell. Whenever the dragged mouse leaves the cell where the `EventHandler` resides, the updating stops. Whenever the dragged mouse enters the cell, the updating continues.
2. When the rectangle is dragged, not even `Dynamic@MousePosition@"ScreenScaled"` gets updated outside of the cell, though it has nothing to do with the `EventHandler`, and it is updated correctly on its own (i.e. when EventHandler is not triggered).

The problem is more general: the mouse coordinates over the full screen cannot be accessed in any construction I've tried, not just in `EventHandler`s. Note that `MousePosition["coords"]` is equivalent to `CurrentValue[{"MousePosition","coords"}]`, and as such, the latter fails as well.

**Question: How to access global mouse coordinates in a dynamic structure such as an EventHandler?**

**EDIT:**

What I want is to create an object (e.g. a button) that accepts/processes/displays the global mousecoordinates **only when** the mouse is dragged.

Comment: As to point 2. This also happens if you drag anything outside of the rectangle cell, so it's unrelated to the EventHandler. Dragged mouse movements are simply not seen by `MousePosition`. Point 1 is the designed behaviour. Events are restricted to the objects used as the first argument.

Comment: As per @SjoerdC.deVries comment the mouse coordinates will be limited to the bounding coordinates of the event handler argument. What real world thing would you like to be able to do? Perhaps there are work arounds (?)

Comment: I gotta go now so no time to investigate or build an answer, but:

Comment: @Sjoerd, Mike: But this is simply not true. I also expected that the `EventHandler` can only register movement inside the `EventHandler`'s argument, but it **can** register it throughout the whole cell **outside** the rectangle, i.e. right of it.

Comment: as to point 1, you won't get it with EventHandler, but I'm pretty sure you can get it done by DynamicWrapper[Graphics, pt=MousePosition]

Comment: As to point 2, I don't think it's not accessible, but that the front end just doesn't show you updated stuff when you are dragging. Try any dynamic thing like Dynamic@Clock[] and drag your mouse. It probably updates the variables properly anyway. Not sure

Comment: @IstvánZachar event handler will register/display etc. the movements anywhere but to activate an event you need to be within the event region. If you just want to make use of the mouse position in some way then I'd wrap Dynamic around some function that takes the mouse position. `EventHandler` doesn't seem like the answer IMO.

Comment: @Mike. Your explanation is still inconsistent: while the **event is activated** correctly as it originates from the event region (i.e. position update is activated by dragging), but the eventhandler **does not** register/display movements everywhere (e.g. outside of cell. Mind that it is not restricted to the rectangle, but to the cell.). My problem is that I have a controller, that should access the global mouse position when the mouse is dragged.

Comment: @IstvánZachar maybe there is some confusion. On my system when I drag the mouse within the event region the global mouse coordinates are being updated. I do not understand what you mean about registering movements everywhere. Your first dynamic does this. The second dynamic is dependent solely on the event (variable "pt"). The event is dependent solely on mouse dragging within the event region (to set "pt"). Your code works exactly as I would expect it to.

Comment: @Mike please see edited points 1 and 2. I find this issue confusing for many reasons, one is that there is no proper language to describe dynamic dependencies in English :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DynamicModule[{pressed = False},
 Deploy@EventHandler[DynamicWrapper[
    Graphics[{Dynamic[If[pressed, Gray, Black]], Rectangle[]}, 
     ImageSize -> 50, AspectRatio -> 2],
    If[pressed, pt = f[MousePosition@"ScreenScaled"]]
    ],
   {"MouseDown" :> (pressed = True), "MouseUp" :> (pressed = False)}]
 ]

Dynamic@pt
```

Answer (score 3):

I am still not totally sure that I understand what you want but it seems like you want to be able to drag the mouse anywhere -- not just in a specific event region -- and have those coordinates displayed or do something with the coordinates. If that is the case then I think that `NotebookEventAction` might be useful. This button toggles between two states:

```
on = True;
Button["On/Off",
 If[TrueQ[on],
  SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
   NotebookEventActions :> {"MouseDragged" :> (pt1 = 
        MousePosition@"ScreenScaled")}]; on = ! on,
  SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions :> {}];
  on = ! on
  ],
 ImageSize -> 100
 ]


Dynamic@pt1
```

When you switch it on you will find that you can drag the mouse anywhere in the notebook and see the coordinates displayed while the mouse is being dragged. You need to switch this on and off because assigning behaviour to a dragged mouse deactivates the normal mouse dragged functionality -- which is why this is normally confined only to an event region.

Comment: While it works nicely, I prefer Rojo's solution as it does the same without manipulating Notebook options.