# Selecting regions from the screen to capture dynamically

Tags: dynamic, eventhandler

I know that by using `CurrentScreenImage` with some coordinates that I can capture regions of my screen. I would like to be able to capture a rectangular region of my screen by clicking and dragging a rectangle, using some dynamic functionality and `MousePosition["ScreenAbsolute"]`, and passing the coordinates of this rectangle to `CurrentScreenImage`. But I run into a couple of snags.

1. `Dynamic[MousePosition["ScreenAbsolute"]]` stops tracking the pointer as soon as it leaves the notebook window.
2. Modifying some code from [How to access off-cell mouse position inside an EventHandler?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7858/how-to-access-off-cell-mouse-position-inside-an-eventhandler), I can at least click *within* a region of the notebook, drag outside of the notebook, and retain the tracking of the pointer while the click is still held. Also, it records successfully the mouse un-click, outside of the notebook. So maybe tracking the pointer outside the window isn't hopeless.
3. But of course, I cannot figure out at all how to get the mouse position and first click recorded while the pointer is outside the notebook.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
DynamicModule[{pressed = True}, 
 Deploy@EventHandler[
   DynamicWrapper[
    Graphics[{Dynamic[If[pressed, Gray, Black]], Rectangle[]}, 
     ImageSize -> 100, AspectRatio -> 1], 
    If[pressed, 
     pt = f[MousePosition@
        "ScreenAbsolute"]]], {"MouseDown" :> ({topLeft, 
        pressed} = {MousePosition["ScreenAbsolute"], True}), 
    "MouseUp" :> ({bottomRight, 
        pressed} = {MousePosition["ScreenAbsolute"], False})}]]

Dynamic@pt
Dynamic[{topLeft, bottomRight}]
```

I will also mention that the reason I don't just manually take these screenshots and put them into Mathematica is that I have a very dynamic, real-time application in mind and I would like it to be as easy as click-dragging a box to put the image data into the notebook for immediate processing. (I guess it doesn't have to be a click per-se; it could also be a key command. But I need to be able to do it without the notebook being the focused window on the desktop.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach (code below):

[image]

This works by:

1. Creating a semi-transparent full-screen window with things such as scrollbars etc. disabled
2. Attaching (see [`AttachCell`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AttachCell.html)) a `Graphics` to the window, so that we can easily draw arbitrary things onto the canvas
3. Using [`NotebookEventActions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookEventActions.html) to listen for two mouse clicks
4. Waiting for the second click and returning the result

*(Please note that the current version has some limitations when it comes to multi-monitor setups and non-default screen scaling settings)*

```
selectArea[] := Module[
  {
   pts = {{0, 0}, Dynamic@MousePosition["ScreenAbsolute"]},
   i = 0,
   nb, size
   },
  nb = CreateWindow[{},
    WindowOpacity -> 0.5,
    Saveable -> False, Editable -> False,
    WindowElements -> {},
    WindowToolbars -> {},
    ShowCellBracket -> False,
    CellInsertionPointCell -> Cell[],
    WindowSize -> Full,
    NotebookEventActions -> {"MouseClicked" :> (
        pts[[++i]] = MousePosition["ScreenAbsolute"];
        If[i == 2, DialogReturn@pts];
        )}
    ];
  size = AbsoluteCurrentValue[nb, WindowSize];
  AttachCell[
   nb, Graphics[
    Dynamic@If[
      i == 0,
      {},
      Scale[
       {
        Transparent,
        Rectangle[Scaled@{0, 0}, Scaled@{1, 1}],
        EdgeForm@{Red, Thick}, FaceForm@None, Rectangle @@ pts
        }, {1, -1}
       ]
      ],
    ImageSize -> size, ImageMargins -> {100, 100},
    PlotRange -> 
     Transpose@{{0, 0}, AbsoluteCurrentValue[nb, WindowSize]}
    ],
   {Left, Top},
   Automatic,
   {Left, Top}
   ];
  While[i < 2, Pause@0.1];
  1 + Round[pts ]
  ]

pts = selectArea[]
(* {{497, 311}, {905, 588}} *)
```

Comment: You possess powers beyond contemplation